# How to get arrows automatically at the edges of lines (linear inequalities lines)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arrows, tikz-arrows

I would like to get the arrows as shown in figure, for the linear inequalities representing it corresponding direction of solution space. Kindly help me. [image]

```
 \documentclass[12pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[title={},ylabel={$x_2$},ymin=0,ymax=100,ytick={10, 20,...,100}, unbounded coords=jump, xmin=0,xmax=100,xtick={0,10,20,...,100},xlabel={$ x_1$},width=15.0cm,height=11.0cm,enlargelimits =false, grid,legend cell align=left, legend style={at={(0.8,0.96)},anchor=north}]
 \addplot+[smooth,ultra thick,color=red,mark=none]
 coordinates{
 (0,72)
 (54,0)
 };
 \addplot+[smooth,ultra thick,dashed,color=blue,mark=none]
 coordinates{
 (0,64)
 (98,0)
 };
 \addplot+[only marks,color=black,fill=black,mark=*]
 coordinates{
 (12,56)
 };
 \addplot+[thin,color=yellow!40,fill=yellow!40,mark=none]
 coordinates{
 (0.1,0.1)
 (53.5,0.1)
 (12,55.5)
 (0.1,63.5)
 (0.1,0.1)
 };
 \end{axis} 
 \node[text width=3.5cm] at (2.29,2.6) {Feasible Region};
 \node[text width=3.5cm] at (2.1,2.05) {(or) Solution Space};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Add `clip=false` option to `axis` environment and draw lines from desired point. For example `\draw[-latex](axis cs:0,64)--++(240:10);`

Comment: @ferahfeza that works, thank you, but is there any automated way in accomplishing this? because it will be cumbersome to calculate the angle for the arrows all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `calc` library. First store the end points of the lines in symbolic coordinates `(r0)` and `(r1)` for the red plot,

```
 \addplot+[smooth,ultra thick,color=red,mark=none]
 coordinates{
 (0,72)
 (54,0)
 } coordinate[pos=0] (r0) coordinate[pos=1](r1);
```

and likewise for the blue plot. Then use the calc syntax of section **13.5.4 The Syntax of Distance Modifiers** of pgfmanual v3.1.5 to draw the orthogonal lines *after* `\end{axis}` (to avoid to be clipped) with

```
 \path[thick,-stealth] (r0) edge ($(r0)!1cm!-90:(r1)$)
 (r1) edge ($(r1)!1cm!90:(r0)$);
```

Full code and result:

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[title={},ylabel={$x_2$},ymin=0,ymax=100,ytick={10, 20,...,100}, unbounded coords=jump, xmin=0,xmax=100,xtick={0,10,20,...,100},xlabel={$ x_1$},width=15.0cm,height=11.0cm,enlargelimits =false, grid,legend cell align=left, legend style={at={(0.8,0.96)},anchor=north}]
 \addplot+[smooth,ultra thick,color=red,mark=none]
 coordinates{
 (0,72)
 (54,0)
 } coordinate[pos=0] (r0) coordinate[pos=1](r1);
 \addplot+[smooth,ultra thick,dashed,color=blue,mark=none]
 coordinates{
 (0,64)
 (98,0)
 } coordinate[pos=0] (b0) coordinate[pos=1](b1); 
 \addplot+[only marks,color=black,fill=black,mark=*]
 coordinates{
 (12,56)
 };
 \addplot+[thin,color=yellow!40,fill=yellow!40,mark=none]
 coordinates{
 (0.1,0.1)
 (53.5,0.1)
 (12,55.5)
 (0.1,63.5)
 (0.1,0.1)
 };
 \end{axis} 
 \node[text width=3.5cm] at (2.29,2.6) {Feasible Region};
 \node[text width=3.5cm] at (2.1,2.05) {(or) Solution Space};
 \path[thick,-stealth] (r0) edge ($(r0)!1cm!-90:(r1)$)
 (r1) edge ($(r1)!1cm!90:(r0)$)
 (b0) edge ($(b0)!1cm!-90:(b1)$)
 (b1) edge ($(b1)!1cm!90:(b0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another approach is to use `decorations.markings`. Then you can introduce a style such that you only have to add the `end arrows` key to the respective plot. The length and the style are stored in the pgf keys `vert arrow length` and `varrow`, respectively.

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[vert arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,
    decoration={markings,
    mark=at position #1 with {%
     \draw[varrow] (0,0) -- (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vert arrow length});}}}},
    end arrows/.style={vert arrow/.list={0,1}},
    varrow/.style={-stealth,thick,black,solid},
    vert arrow length/.initial=-1cm
    ]
 \begin{axis}[title={},ylabel={$x_2$},ymin=0,ymax=100,ytick={10, 20,...,100},
 unbounded coords=jump, xmin=0,xmax=100,xtick={0,10,20,...,100},xlabel={$
 x_1$},width=15.0cm,height=11.0cm,enlargelimits =false, grid,legend cell
 align=left, legend style={at={(0.8,0.96)},anchor=north},clip=false]
 \addplot+[ultra thick,color=red,mark=none,end arrows]
 coordinates{
 (0,72)
 (54,0)
 };
 \addplot+[ultra thick,dashed,color=blue,mark=none,end arrows]
 coordinates{
 (0,64)
 (98,0)
 }; 
 \addplot+[only marks,color=black,fill=black,mark=*]
 coordinates{
 (12,56)
 };
 \addplot+[thin,color=yellow!40,fill=yellow!40,mark=none]
 coordinates{
 (0.1,0.1)
 (53.5,0.1)
 (12,55.5)
 (0.1,63.5)
 (0.1,0.1)
 };
 \end{axis} 
 \node[text width=3.5cm] at (2.29,2.6) {Feasible Region};
 \node[text width=3.5cm] at (2.1,2.05) {(or) Solution Space};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Schrödinger's cat thank you very much. This works perfectly fine and this is what I was  looking for.